# I cannot figure out why i get an error in this function

Tags: javascript

I cannot understand why it can read property 'name' but it can't read property 'price'.. I defined both of them in the function addDishToCourse, so I can't see what could cause the problem

```js
addDishToCourse(courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
    const dish = {

      name: dishName,
      price: dishPrice

    };
    this._courses[courseName].push(dish)
  },


  generateRandomMeal: function() {
    const appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizers');
    const mains = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('mains');
    const desserts = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('desserts');
    const totalPrice = appetizer.price + mains.price + desserts.price;
    return `Your meal is ${appetizer.name}, ${mains.name}, ${desserts.name}. The price is ${totalPrice}.`
  }
```

`getRandomDishFromCourse: function(courseName){
  let dishes = menu._courses[courseName]
  return dishes[Math.floor(Math.random() * dishes.length)];`

this is the error:
const totalPrice = appetizer.price + mains.price + desserts.price;
                                                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined
    at Object.generateRandomMeal

Comment: Did you inspect what returns from `getRandomDishFromCourse` ?

Comment: Its **this.getRandomDishFromCourse('desserts')** might be returning null, that's why it's showing the error. please debug what you are getting in this line.

Comment: add code for getRandomDishFromCourse("...") it might be generating some error

Comment: You code above works fine given the correct inputs [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/porexugiji/edit?js,console) - you need to ensure the inputs are correct.

Comment: There may be a scope issue. What is the context of these methods. Some declared as part of an object literal and `addDishToCourse()` as a class method.

Comment: Please post a working example after reading: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

one of the try these mains, desserts or appetizer is undefined. 
try defaulting them to empty object.

````
addDishToCourse (courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
   const dish = {

     name : dishName,
     price : dishPrice

   };
   this._courses[courseName].push(dish)
 },


generateRandomMeal: function(){
  const appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizers') || {};
  const mains = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('mains') || {};
  const desserts = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('desserts') || {};
  const totalPrice = appetizer.price + mains.price + desserts.price;
  return `Your meal is ${appetizer.name}, ${mains.name}, ${desserts.name}. The price is ${totalPrice}.`
}```
````